# faster print with format #python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, printing, io

I often need to print something out in python3. I know 3 methods as the following code.
From my test the method 3 is the slowest, but I don't know which one is faster due to unstable test enviorment.

What is the fast and most pythonic way to print?

```
import time
t = time.time()

for _ in range(10000):
    # method 1
    # print("some words....%s,%s,%i"%("arg_str1", "arg_str2",33))
    # method 2
    print("some words....{},{},{}".format("arg_str1", "arg_str2", 33))
    # method 3
    # print("some words....","arg_str1", "arg_str2",33 )
    # method 4 ....
print(time.time()-t)
```

Comment: (1) You should use module `timeit` for profiling. (2) Formatted strings are the fastest.

Comment: you didn't metion method 4 `print(f'{some} {vars}')`

Answer (score 2):

you can use an f string which is basically just a pretty .format. Format is the quickest way to do what you are seeking. To insert string values you just need to use the different quote type than what the f string has like this:

```
print(f"some words....{'arg_str1'},{'arg_str2'},{33}")
# Speed: 0.012160062789916992
```

Also, if you really want fast, the best way to do this is to not print every iteration, instead appending the strings to a list/another string THEN printing the string out. (takes only about 0.007600307464599609)

```
import time
t = time.time()

printString = []
for _ in range(10000):
    # method 1
    # print("some words....%s,%s,%i"%("arg_str1", "arg_str2",33))
    # method 2
    # printString += f"some words....{'arg_str1'},{'arg_str2'},{33}"
    printString.append(f"some words....{'arg_str1'},{'arg_str2'},{33}")
    # print(f"some words....{'arg_str1'},{'arg_str2'},{33}")
    # method 3
    # print("some words....","arg_str1", "arg_str2",33 )
    # method 4 ....
print('\n'.join(printString))
print(time.time()-t)
```

Also Also, using a list comprehension makes this even quicker. (something like 0.005544662475)

```
import time
t = time.time()

printString = [f"some words....{'arg_str1'},{'arg_str2'},{33}" for _ in range(10000)]
print('\n'.join(printString))
print(time.time()-t)
```

Comment: is `+=` really fastest? since we all know in java, c# etc there are `stringbuilders`, maybe there's similiar equivalents in python？

Comment: @LeiYang see my updated code, using a list got this down to like 0.006 seconds compared to 0.0085/0.01x of the other methods

Comment: found [a useful website](https://zetcode.com/python/fstring/) for formatting f-String